# facebook set iframe height auto

Tags: facebook, iframe, height, facebook-iframe

I would set auto height to my facebook iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/widgets/like.php?href=<? the_permalink(); ?>&layout=button_count&width=450&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&show_faces=false&height=24"
                            scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
                            style="border:none;">
                        </iframe>
```

How can I do?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: <iframe height="100%" /> for example?

Comment: see here in the sidebar http://www.michelepierri.it/blog/#.UdaukfkdfD7

Comment: not work. It is has more height than like button

Comment: Ok so if I look at your code, the facebook button height is 20px and the width is 300 px. 20 px height because you set that in your style code style="border:none;height: 20px;" and width of 300 because you don't set any value to it and it takes it's parent's (the grid) width. So what do you actually want, I don't understand the problem?

Comment: solved deleting &height=24 thanks.